# SQL Apply random part in seconds to a timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I have a field `Date` that is of type `timestamp` and as default it is set to `current_timestamp`.

I need it to be changed randomly (by adding random amount of seconds). Essentially, what I'm looking for is something alike:

```
SET Date = current_timestamp + x
```

where `x` is provides an arbitrary integer

For example **x** can be one of those:

```
1000
Round(Rand() * 1000)
```

Expected result (proper timestamp) sometimes, but very rarely shows up, but almost all the time it is

```
00-00-0000 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using `DATE_ADD`

```
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL ROUND(RAND() * 1000) SECONDS)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The correct formula is:
`SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL ROUND(RAND() * 1000) SECOND)`
Solved.

Comment: Aha, forgot to not use that 's' on seconds. :)